# Multiprocessing in C

Tags: c, windows, multiprocessing, sapi

I once watched a movie called "War Games". I wanted to emulate that program in the movie. I wrote a simple program that can print and then speak the sentence, or the other way around. I want the program to execute both at the same time. How do I do that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sapi.h>

ISpVoice *pVoice = NULL;

void printSmoothly(wchar_t *Str);

int main(void)
{
    if (FAILED(::CoInitialize(NULL)))
        return FALSE;

    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, 
                    IID_ISpVoice, (void **)&pVoice);

    wchar_t *sentence = L"Greetings professor falken,What would you like to do ?";

    // how can i execute these two at the same time ?
    printSmoothly(sentence);
    pVoice->Speak(sentence, 0, NULL);

    pVoice->Release();

    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}

void printSmoothly(wchar_t *Str)
{
    size_t len = wcslen( Str ) , n ;

    for( n = 0 ; n < len ; n++ )
    {
        wprintf( L"%c", Str[n] );

        Sleep(50);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this "C/C++" of which you speak? Which language are you _really_ using?

Comment: I would prefer C, you know.

Comment: Then let's go with that. Include `wchar.h`, change "C/C++" to "C" and remove the [tag:c++] tag. Then you're going to have to do something about those member functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the speaking to be *asynchronous*.

Fortunately, `Speak` has a flag for that, so you don't need to dig into multiprocessing yet:

```
pVoice->Speak(sentence, SPF_ASYNC, NULL);
printSmoothly(sentence);
```

Note that you need to start the speech first, or it won't start until the printing has finished.

You'll also need to take care that you don't `Release` and `CoUninitialize` until the speaking has finished.
This will happen if you print faster than the speech, for instance.
(Asynchronous programming is much harder in reality than it is in Hollywood.)

Comment: This isn't very efficient.i tried it with a sentence that has '\n' character,and it stopped speaking before reading the entire thing.

Comment: That sounds like a crucial bug, not an inefficiency.

Comment: I adjusted time frames,and put a condition on the '\n; character.your answer is acceptable.